# Multiple Custom Post Type in Taxonomy Archive Causing White Screen

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, archive-template

So basically I'm trying to add multiple custom post type in my taxonomy archive. Here's my code:

```
    <?php
        $args_trip = array ( 
            'post_type' => 'trip' ,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array (
                array ( 
                    'taxonomy' => 'destination',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term
                )
            )
        );

        $trips = new WP_Query( $args_trip );        
        ?>

    <?php 
    if ( $trips->have_posts() ) : ?>        
    <div class="archive-grid">
    <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $trips->have_posts() ) : $trips->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'trip' );

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();                    
    ?>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <?php 
    $args_wisata = array ( 
        'post_type' => 'wisata' ,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array (
            array ( 
                'taxonomy' => 'destination',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term
            )
        )
    );

    $wisatas = new WP_Query( $args_wisata );

    if ( $wisatas->have_posts() ) : 
    ?>

    <div class="archive-grid">

    <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $wisatas->have_posts() ) : $wisatas->the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'wisata' );


        endwhile;

    ?>

    </div>
```

The code above meant to output TWO different custom post type TRIP & WISATA within taxonomy archive.

BUT it always causing white screen, but when it only looping ONE custom post type, it works fine. Here's the code for only one custom post type:

```
    <?php
$args_trip = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'trip' ,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array (
        array ( 
            'taxonomy' => 'destination',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term
        )
    )
);

$trips = new WP_Query( $args_trip );        
?>

<?php 
if ( $trips->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="archive-grid">
    <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $trips->have_posts() ) : $trips->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'trip' );

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();            

?>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

I don't know what might be causing this? Really frustrate me... Please someone help me! Lol.

NOTE: my `wp-config.php` already has `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` but there is no error shown, only blank white page.

Comment: You forgot to close the `if` - add `<?php endif; ?>` after those two `</div>` (the closing tag for the `archive-grid` DIV).

Comment: WOW thank you so much! I've been blind the whole time!! I'm still very new about PHP and the solution actually so simple lol. Thank you!! @SallyCJ

Comment: No problem Syamsul. Even I sometimes make such a (silly) mistake.. :) And if I may give you a tip: If you ever see that "white screen" again (on other pages) - and you couldn't find anything wrong in your code, then try looking for any PHP errors in the page source (HTML), and/or (enable debugging and) check the `error_log` file. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer it myself to close this question / thread.

From @Sally CJ

> You forgot to close the if - add `<?php endif; ?>` after those two `</div>` (the closing tag for the archive-grid DIV)